# Como obtener un dato que envio desde un controlador de laravel a una solicitud http con axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, axios

estoy queriendo recibir un dato desde un controlador de laravel a una solicitud http de axios, es un  valor numérico que necesito asignar a una variable para poder hacer uso de ella.

Simplemente lo que estoy haciendo en mi controlador obtener un valor

```
public function getNroBoleta() {
    $nro_boleta = DB::select('SELECT num_comprobante + 1 AS nro_boleta FROM ventas ORDER BY num_comprobante DESC LIMIT 1');
    return ['nro_boleta' => $nro_boleta];
}
```

y lo quiero recibir en mi vista con una solicitud http de axios.

```
var respuesta = [];
            axios.get('/venta/getNroBoleta').then(function (response) {
                respuesta = response.data;
                console.log(respuesta);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
 {
  "nro_boleta": [
    {
      "nro_boleta": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Como puedo hacer para utilizar el numero que estoy recibiendo para almacenarlo en una variable y poder hacer lo que se me antoje de el?
Pd: probe de esta forma para ver si no recogia el valor por su posicion y no me funciono

```
console.log(respuesta[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que primero hay un objeto y luego un array de objetos JavaScript, sería algo así:

```
respuesta.nro_boleta[0].nro_boleta
```

Para entender un poco más sobre como funcionan los objetos `{}` y los array `[]`, puedes ver más información en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos

Comment: Muchas gracias.. aunque no entiendo muy bien como es que funciono de esta forma, pero igual. muchas gracias

Comment: Ya agregué un enlace en español donde puedes ver detalladamente cómo funcionan los objetos

Comment: oh.. gracias devuelta